# Restart workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

If I have Collect Data From User Action and based on approver answer I need to restart workflow . Is it applicable using SharePoint Designer 2013?

Comment: You could make it a separate branch in the workflow instead, there is no restart option.

Comment: What you mean by separate branch ? Can you please give me example as I did not get what you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

you can create a console application and terminate workflows and restart it using C# code, then create a windows job to run it automatically.

The following articles for your reference:

SharePoint: Cancelling or Terminating Workflows using C# and CSOM

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31910.sharepoint-cancelling-or-terminating-workflows-using-c-and-csom.aspx

Start a workflow instance using CSOM API from a console application

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Start-a-workflow-instance-ab5ffecb

Best Regards,